# How to change product template for bundle products?

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, bundled-product

Is the any way to have separate view.phtml for simple and bundled products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.

Magento already deals them separately.

Check these template files:

For simple: `template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

For bundle: `template/bundle/catalog/product/view.phtml`

Now if you want to change bundle template then have this in your local.xml

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle translate="label" module="bundle">
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method='setTemplate'><template>path/to/your/template/view.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
```

You would want to copy the content from `template/catalog/product/view.phtml` to `path/to/your/template/view.phtml`.

Comment: I tried same as you suggested, but bundle product page is blank , except header and footer. can you check  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194755/change-product-page-layout-and-design-for-the-bundle-product-in-magento-1-9