# Change product page layout and design for the bundle product, in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1, custom-template

**What I did**

1) Moved bundle folder from rwd to my active custom them template folder.

2) In `app/design/frontend/rwd/ysv/layout`  addedd below code,

```
<catalog_product_view> // under this 
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle translate="label" module="bundle">
        <reference name="product.info">
            <action method='setTemplate'><template>template/catalog/product/bundle/view.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
</catalog_product_view>
```

3) Copied **view.phtml** from

`app/design/frontend/rwd/ysv/template/catalog/product` to `app/design/frontend/rwd/ysv/template/catalog/product/bundle`

[image: error_layout]

Still same template is shown for bundle and simple product.

**Update: 1**

If i Move (as suggested below) `<PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>` tag out of `<catalog_product_view>` tag
then view of bundle/view.phtml is loaded (`shown when i on Template Path Hints`)but except header files and footer files nothing is loaded.

**Update 1.1**

I tried to replicate a block section in `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/catalog.xml`

```
 <PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle translate="label" module="catalog">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Simple)</label>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_bundle" name="product.info.bundle" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/bundle.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.simple.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                    <label>Product Extra Info</label>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_bundle" name="product.info.availability" as="product_type_availability" template="catalog/product/view/type/availability/bundle.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
```

still no chagnes.

Comment: after applying your changes is it coming from your theme or from rwd  ? and have you cleared the cache ?

Comment: @Piyush its coming from `ysv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `maddy` as current theme from admin instead of `ysv` to load your layout under `rwd/maddy` theme unless `maddy` is the parent theme of `ysv`

**Update**

Move your `<PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>` tag out of `<catalog_product_view>` tag

Also the change below code

```
<action method='setTemplate'><template>template/catalog/product/bundle/view.phtml</template></action>
```

To this

```
<action method='setTemplate'><template>catalog/product/bundle/view.phtml</template></action>
```

Comment: that was my mistake actually it has to be `ysv`

Comment: still issues are same

Comment: If i move `<PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>` tag out of `<catalog_product_view>` tag . bundle/view.phtml template is loaded but except header and footer, nothing else populated.

Comment: if content area is not populated your template may not exist at the given path

Comment: Hello sir, after changes in catalog.xml view of the bundle is loaded.I will update my post once i reach to office

Comment: sure can please check this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195936/get-all-product-images-on-product-view-page-separately